# Add NuGet package (ie. xunit.runner.console) at solution level

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, xunit

I need a NuGet (example *xunit.runner.console*) to run UT from command line.

Right now in one of project I have added xunit.runner.console as dependency so it is downloaded, path is known and I can use it in my build script.

This Project was removed and build-script is broken now. I will need to add it to another project, but the same situation can occur again (or other reasons).

I there a way to download this package but don't link it with concrete project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the [nuget cli](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then get the package needed using the build script. So, to answer your question, you can just use it in the build script and fetch the package before starting to build your project.